# git - the requested URL returned error: 400

Tags: git, github, git-bash

When I do

> git push --set-upstream origin main

It returned

> fatal: unable to access
> 'https://github.com/RozuRoseMary/my-app.git~/': The requested URL
> returned error: 400

I use git version 2.35.1.windows.2

Comment: Try removing the trailing `~/` in .git/config for the origin upstream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
This may be due to the use of an SSH key.

Try deleting the link to the remote repository and add a new link to it using SSH

> `git remote rm origin`

> `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git`